# Integration in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

Let $C([0,a],\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the set of continuous functions defined from $[0,a]$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $a>0$ is a real number. Let $f:[0,a] \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuous function.For $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ define $\Vert x \Vert= \Vert x_1,x_2,\ldots , x_n \Vert= \max \{\vert x_1 \vert, \vert x_2 \vert,\ldots , \vert x_n \vert \}$.

Prove that $$ \Big\Vert \int\limits_0^a [f(s,u(s))-f(s,v(s))]ds \Big\Vert \leq \int\limits_0^a \Vert f(s,u(s))-f(s,v(s)) \Vert ds,$$  where $u,v \in C([0,a],\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?  For example, are you familiar with Minkowski's inequality?

Comment: Yes I"m familiar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u$ is a vector with $\sum_{i=1}^{n} |u_i|=1$  and $\langle u, v  \rangle$ denotes $\sum_{i=1}^{n} u_iv_i$ then $\langle u, \int_0^{a} [f(s,u(s))-f(s,v(s)] \, ds \rangle=\int_0^{a}  \langle u, [f(s,u(s)-f(s,v(s)]  \rangle \, ds\leq RHS$. Take sup over all  $u$. Details: let $g(s)=f(s,u(s))-f(s,v(s))$. Then $g$ maps $[0,a]$ into $\mathbb R^{n}$. Write $$g=(g_1,g_2,...,g_n)$$ . [$g_i$'s are real valued functions]. By definition $\int_0^{a}g(s)ds$ is the vector $$(\int_0^{a}g_1(s)ds,\int_0^{a}g_2(s)ds,...,\int_0^{a}g_n(s)ds)$$. If $u=(u_1,u_2,...,u_n)$ is as above then $$\langle u, \int_0^{a} g(s) \, ds \rangle= \sum_{i=1}^{n} u_i\int_0^{a}g_i(s)ds=\int_0^{a}\sum_{i=1}^{n}u_ig_i(s)ds$$. But $\sum_{i=1}^{n}u_ig_i(s) \leq \|g(s)\|$ so we get $$\langle u, \int_0^{a} [f(s,u(s))-f(s,v(s)] \, ds \rangle \leq \int_0^{a} \|g(s)\| \, ds$$ and the last quantity is the right hand side of your inequality. it is easy to see that for any vector $x$, $\sup (\{\langle u,x \rangle :\sum_{i=1}^{n} |u_i|=1\})=\|x\|$. Hence, if you take sup over all $u$ you will get the desired inequality.

Comment: Please explain a bit more. I'm not able to get it.

Comment: This answer isn't quite correct: the norm $\lVert x \rVert$ given in the question is not generated by an inner product, so Cauchy-Schwarz does not apply.

Comment: @Strants Thanks. I have revised the answer.